# pandas - concat columns by repeats values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, pandas-groupby

I am trying to concatenate the columns of my data frame if they have the same value in a field. I'll explain myself. Suppose I have this data frame:

```
peter   brian   peter   mike   brian   
  2       3       4       5      6
  4       6       1       7      5
```

then I want to concatenate the columns taking into account values repeated in the first row:

```
peter   brian   mike
  2       3       5
  4       6       7
  4       6
  1       5
```

It is important to clarify that I cannot concatenate by directly calling the name ("peter", "mike", etc) since the data frame I want to use this in has thousands of columns. The idea is to automatically find the repeated names and concatenate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way using `pd.concat` with NumPy arrays:

```
res = pd.concat([pd.Series(df[col].values.flatten(), name=col) \
                 for col in df.columns.unique()], axis=1)

print(res)

   peter  brian  mike
0      2      3   5.0
1      4      6   7.0
2      4      6   NaN
3      1      5   NaN
```

Note `mike` is forced to `float` since it contains `NaN` values.

**Explanation**

- `df.columns.unique` extracts unique column names.
- `df[col].values.flatten` extracts the values from all series for a particular name as a NumPy array, and then flattens them into a 1-dimensional array.
- `pd.Series` converts the array into a series object.
- We iterate over all such unique column names via a list comprehension.
- `pd.concat` concatenates a list of series into a dataframe.

Comment: Can you explain the code a little bit, please? I'd also like to ask: what does it mean the "\" after of name = col and before the for?

Comment: Backslash is just a [line continuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125328/what-does-a-backslash-by-itself-mean-in-python) character in Python. I've also added an explanation.