# What does '\' '.\' and '\.' mean in context of SQL Alchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to know what the syntax \ or .\ or . means in SQL Alchemy when used with filters.

```py
count = db.session.query(Redirect404).filter(Redirect404.site_code == self.site_code)\
.filter(Redirect404.url == str(candidate_url))\
.count()
```

Comment: A nice explanation here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125328/what-does-a-backslash-by-itself-mean-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing. This is Python line continuation. Python typically doesn't allow you to split a line into several. I.e. if

```
foo = bar().baz()
```

is a valid command,

```
foo = bar().
      baz()
```

is a syntax error. There are exceptions: triple-quoted strings can span several lines:

```
foo = """bar
      baz"""
```

anything in any kind of parentheses can as well:

```
print(1,
      2)

foo["bar" +
    baz"]

foo = {
    "bar": "baz"
}
```

And finally, you can explicitly cancel a newline by placing `\` at the end of the line:

```
foo = bar + \
    baz
```

So what you have in your code is this line:

```
count = db.session.query(Redirect404).filter(Redirect404.site_code == self.site_code).filter(Redirect404.url == str(candidate_url)).count()
```

made readable by breaking it up into three lines, with the help of some backslashy newline cancellation.