# python \ in a function, usage?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I ran across the following function watching a tutorial. Can someone help me understand the `\` usage before the `.to_file`. I did search around but can't find an answer. Pointers to where to read about it are welcome!

```
pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(df)\
    .to_file("/Users/superavit/Desktop/veryinterestingdatasetsummary.html")
```

Comment: it is a line continuation -- essentially escaping the newline.  it would be a syntax error otherwise

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125328/what-does-a-backslash-by-itself-mean-in-python

Comment: thanks so basically the .to_file could be written as a continuation to the top statement but the \ is added for readability . Thanks!

Comment: it's a line continuation (first line and second line are one)

Comment: @jason: no, because Python doesn't have a way to denote the ends of statements (like ; in other languages), by default a statement ends at the end of a line. So the \ is necessary.

Comment: @jason \ is added for interpreter, otherwise your code will not work

Comment: @RemcoGerlich the \ isn't necessary, parenthesis can (and arguably should) be used instead

Comment: Yes OK, I was just noting that it would not be a continuation without the \. That there are other ways went a bit too far I thought...

Answer (score 1):

This backslash tells Python that the next line is the continuation of the current line. So, your code is equivalent to:

```
pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(df).to_file("/Users/superavit/Desktop/veryinterestingdatasetsummary.html")
```

Without the backslash, Python will treat the second line as a *standalone line* and will raise a `SyntaxError` because a line can't start with a dot (`.`) unless it's a decimal point in a floating-point literal, like `.5`.

This method of escaping the new line is used mostly for readability purposes to avoid very long lines of code.