# What does <\ mean in Python?

Tags: python

I've been looking a this code that uses numpy to reduce the size of a dataframe.

Here's a snippet

```
                if c_min > np.iinfo(np.int8).min and c_max <\
                  np.iinfo(np.int8).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.int8)
```

Is the `\` there after the `<` due to the newline? Like telling python that the if statement is going to continue on the next line? Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: It's a line continuation character. Generally should be avoided (use parentheses instead)

Comment: To be clear, `'\'` is the line continuation character

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a backslash by itself ('\') mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125328/what-does-a-backslash-by-itself-mean-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

The '\' (backslash) character is the line continuation character which just tells python that the statement will continue on the next line. So

```
if c_min > np.iinfo(np.int8).min and c_max <\
  np.iinfo(np.int8).max:
    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.int8)
```

could just be re-written as:

```
if c_min > np.iinfo(np.int8).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.int8).max:
    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.int8)
```

There is no difference between them logically, it is just personal preference.

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining